# how to make an SQL Join with inequality but just select TOP 1 rows for every mach of the inequality?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, non-equi-join

I have this tables:

table A:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 10 |

table B:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 14 |
| 3 | 10 |

I want all the pairs where A.value >= than B.value. But for every comparison in the WHERE condition i just want the first match. In the example:

I got this query:

```
SELECT * FROM A, B 
WHERE A.date>=B.date;
```

| A_id | A_value | B_id | B_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 20 | 2 | 14 |
| 1 | 20 | 3 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 | 2 | 14 |
| 2 | 15 | 3 | 10 |
| 3 | 10 | 3 | 10 |

but as i said, i just want the first match of every comparison (asume that a_value and b_value are sorted)
So i want to delete (actually ignore) these values:

| A_id | A_value | B_id | B_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2 | 14 |
| 1 | 20 | 3 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 | 3 | 10 |

and obtain:

| A_id | A_value | B_id | B_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 15 | 2 | 14 |
| 3 | 10 | 3 | 10 |

I think i can achieve the result grouping by A_id and A_value and calculating MAX(B_value) but i dont know if this is efficient.

something like this

```
SELECT A.id,A.Value,MAX(B_value) 
FROM A, B 
WHERE A.date>=B.date 
GROUP BY A.id,A.value;
```

So the question is:
Is there a query that can give me the result i need ?

Comment: What exactly is the (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question? [ask] [Help] PS [mre]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` (available in MySQL 8.x). For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    a.id as a_id, a.value as a_value,
    b.id as b_id, b.value as b_value,
    row_number() over(partition by a.id order by b.value desc) as rn
  from a
  join b on a.id = b.id
        and a.value >= b.value
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: They've revised the question to remove the `a.id = b.id` condition.

Comment: You should note that window functions require MySQL 8.x.

Comment: @Barmar Added. However, MySQL 5.x is reaching end of life in 15 months. Most people are probably using 8.x nowadays.

Comment: And you probably also think most people are using PHP 7.x....